# Android studio 3 and Gradle 3.0.0 - Dependency has different version for compile and runtime classpath

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

After updating to Gradle version 3.0.0 and Android Studio 3.0 I'm receiving the following error:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:appNameDebugBuild'.
>
> > Android dependency 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7' has different version for the compile (24.0.0) and runtime (25.4.0)
> >     classpath. You should manually set the same version via
> >     DependencyResolution

I did search for anything with the version 24.0.0 in my project but didnt find anything. On gradle I define a variable with the version 25.4.0 and use it on *compile/implementation* dependencies.

How can I check which library or module is using the version 24.0.0? How can i work around this?

Comment: In the gradle file, there are two version of dependency 24.0.0 and 25.4.0, please make both to same version

Comment: please add your gradle file to question

Comment: @OğuzhanDöngül on gradle file i only have 25.4.0 declared. Cant find anything with 24.0.0.

Comment: @PramodYadav too many gradle files with dependencies to add. Big project being updated.

Comment: If you put your gradle file, we look at it and may see what you are missing(If there is any on your gradle). That's your choice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try adding this **subprojects** block to your main/top level gradle file.
Clean and Build again.

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
       //...
    }

    subprojects {
        project.configurations.all {
            resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { details ->
                if (details.requested.group == 'com.android.support'
                && !details.requested.name.contains('multidex') ) {
                    details.useVersion "25.4.0"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, good approach! But still get the same error. I still can't figure out who is trying to get this 24.0.0

Comment: It did solve the problem. I wasn't applying this code to main gradle file.